# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies integration with Web API correct design

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

After following [Prepare your environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview#prepare-your-environment) and other prerequisites for custom policies, I've met difficulty with how to design my B2C application registrations.

**Requirements**

- Users login with a B2C custom policy into a single page application (SPA) and gain a token which grants them access to a secured web API (Azure App Service).
- During some B2C custom policies, certain [RESTful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) `TechnicalProfile`s also need to securely access the above web API. Let's say the reason is to validate some data.

**My registered Applications right now** *(names are not all real)*

- IdentityExperienceFramework
- ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework
- SPA
- WebAPI

**Setup**

- The **IdentityExperienceFramework** and **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** apps are configured exactly like the documentation describes.
- The **SPA** app is used for the custom policies (login, registration etc).
- The **WebAPI** app exposes a scope which the SPA adds as a delegated permission. It also contains additional Graph API permissions that the web API requires.
- The .NET 6 web API requires authentication with the **WebAPI** app.

**Question**

For the RESTful `TechnicalProfile`, my idea is to generate a client secret in the **WebAPI** app and use it to gain a bearer token in my custom policy. The token can be used to communicate securely with the web API. Is this the correct and secure way? Should I use **IdentityExperienceFramework** for this somehow? Any comments about the overall design?

<sub>I've had lots of difficulty with how to design this after doing many hours of research so I decided to post my first stackoverflow question!</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the RESTful technical profiles you want B2C to act in a similar way to your SPA, it needs to generate a JWT and pass it to the API but there's one key difference - the B2C token doesn't have an authorised user present.

The first thing you'll need to do is [create application permissions on your API app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#step-11-define-web-api-roles-scopes), similar to how you have delegated permissions created  so far. That's because any tokens generated without a user present can only use *application* permissions, not the *delegated* permissions that are available to apps with a user present.

You then need to [set up an app registration representing B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#step-2-register-an-application). I normally set up a separate app registration, but I think you could reuse the **IdentityExperienceFramework** app if you wanted to.

You want to [set up a client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#step-21-create-a-client-secret) on that app then [assign permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#step-22-grant-the-app-permissions-for-the-web-api) from the API app registration to the B2C app registration similar to how you did for your SPA app.

Once you've done that you [can make a `client_credentials` request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#step-3-obtain-an-access-token) from B2C to generate an `access_token` and pass that to your API in the same way you pass your user's `access_token` in your app. You'd do that by [creating a technical profile that requests the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#acquiring-an-access-token) then [updating your API technical profiles to use that token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#change-the-rest-technical-profile-to-use-bearer-token-authentication).

Comment: I will probably create a new app for B2C policies like you described. Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata) client certificate authentication but I think it's more complicated to setup. Do you have any opinion about it versus bearer token auth in terms of security? Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: _Generally_ I'd always go for bearer tokens as they're easy to set up (given you already have the B2C tenant) and consume, you can control which apps they're issued to and what permissions those apps have at runtime, and if an app leaks its secret it's very easy and low impact to kill that secret and generate a new one.